# How do I Pass the Second 'Narrow Gap'?

Tags: mobiloid

To get through the first one, all I had to do was take my turntable off, boost my battery through, and then put it back on.  However, the next one (scanned as 'Narrow Gap 2') has an obstacle in it that my battery can't climb over by itself.

How do I get through here?

[image: Narrow Gap 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling, I came up with the solution.

First, take off the turntable and drive a little ways into the gap.  Then mod your robot and put the turntable back on, but *on top* of your battery (not under it as usual).

[image: Put the turntable on TOP of the battery]

Now your turntable will help you climb up the slopes on either side of the gap, and over the block in the middle.

[image: Passing through/over the gap]